# PHP Should I Use Filesystem DB to store JSON Files

Tags: php, database

My question is regarding the use of the file system as a database to simply hold `JSON` files.

I have came up with this following code, not perfect at all. which I found very easy to store and extract data, using `JSON` files.

My question is, will this DB be good for any large projects? will it work fast? or is the limitation to use this kind of approach is simply security related?

Is there some kind of built-in solution by `PHP` for this kind of things?

Any input on this matter from people who know will be appreciated...

```
class JDB{

    public $path;

    function JDB( $path = __DIR__.'/jdb/' ){
        $this->path = $path;
        if( !file_exists($this->path) ) mkdir($this->path);
    }

    function p($t){
        return $this->path.$t.'.json';
    }

    function get($t){
        return json_decode(file_get_contents( $this->p($t) ));
    }

    function set($t,$c){
        return file_put_contents( $this->p($t), json_encode($c,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) );
    }

    function create( $t, $d = [] ){
        $s = file_put_contents( $this->p($t), json_encode($d) );
        return $s;
    }

    function destroy(){
        $files = glob($this->path.'*'); // get all file names present in folder
        foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
        if(is_file($file))
            unlink($file); // delete the file
        }
    }

    function delete( $t ){
        $s = unlink( $this->p($t) );
        return $s;
    }

    function insert( $t, $d = null ){
        if($d) $d['__uid'] = $t.'_'.$this->uid();
        $c = $this->get($t);
        array_push($c,$d);
        $s = $this->set($t,$c);
        if($s) return $d['__uid'];
    }

    function update($t,$conditions,$u){
        $c = $this->get($t);
        $this->search($c,$conditions,function($object) use (&$c,$u){
            foreach ($u as $key => $value) {
                $object->$key = $value;
            }
        });
        $this->set($t,$c);
    }

    function remove($t,$conditions){
        $c = $this->get($t);
        $this->search($c,$conditions,function($object,$key) use (&$c){
            unset($c[$key]);
        });
        $this->set($t,$c);
    }

    function search( $c, $conditions = [], $fn ){
        $l = count($conditions);
        foreach ($c as $key => $object) {
            $f = 0;
            foreach ($conditions as $k => $v) {
                if( property_exists($object,$k) && ($object->$k == $v) ){
                    $f++;
                    if( $f==$l ) $fn($object,$key);
                }else break;
            }
        }
    }

    function select( $t, $conditions = [] ){
        $c = $this->get($t);
        $r = [];
        $this->search($c,$conditions,function($object) use (&$r){
            array_push($r,$object);
        });
        if (count($r) == 0) return false;
        if (count($r) == 1) return $r[0];
        return $r;
    }

    function count($t){
        $c = $this->get($t);
        return count($c);
    }

    function uid($length = 20) {
        $c = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $cl = strlen($c);
        $uid = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $uid .= $c[rand(0, $cl - 1)];
        }
        return $uid;
    }

}
```

very simple, the question if this is even possible...

### How To Use

```
$db = new JDB();

$db->create('users');
$db->create('pages');

$user_uid = $db->insert('users',[
    'name' => 'a',
    'password' => 'hello world',
    'pages'  => []
]);

$user_uid = $db->insert('users',[
    'name' => 'b',
    'password' => 'hello world',
    'pages'  => []
]);

$page_uid = $db->insert('pages',[
    'name' => 'page 1',
    'content' => 'hello world',
    'users'  => [$user_uid]
]);

$user = $db->select('users',['name'  => 'a']);
$page = $db->select('pages',['users'  => [$user_uid]]);

$db->update('users',['name'  => 'b'],['pages' => [$page->__uid]]);
$db->remove('users',['name'  => 'a']);
```

Comment: Managing unique filenames and race condition might become an issue. Further more this question is offtopic on SO since it is a discussion of actually running code. It might be ontopic on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Thanks I have added a question there as well...